# Asp.Net 5 how make .ts files compile on build instead of just save

Tags: typescript, gulp, asp.net-core

I'd like my .ts files to generate on build and not just on save.  I'd also like it to happen without having to create a gulp task where I specify every file like the examples I keep seeing.  I'm using tsconfig.json files which specify the output so it should be possible to have a build go through all the ts files, use the tsconfig, and output them to their location.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A the moment it's impossible to turn off auto-generation on save in VS. I'm working as fallow with TypeScript files:
- editing files in Atom editor (much better then Visual Studio)
- has watch() task configured which generates files in the background
So that I just refresh the browser and that's it.

Comment: I don't want to stop auto-generation on save, I want to add generation on build but in a generic way where the tsconfig file  will be used to determine the output directory.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Visual Studio Web Essentials plugin. It actually creates gulp tasks but it is much more easy

http://vswebessentials.com/